# window.closed() is true when console debugger is closed, but false when console debugger is open IE behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, yii

windowobj.closed() is coming true always when console debugger is closed in IE browser.

```
 windowobj = window.open(
  url,
  "_blank",
  "resizable=yes,width=1024,height=630,top=0,left=0,status=1"
);

if (!windowobj.closed) {
  var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `window.closed()` ( method) or `window.closed` (property) ? Since `window.closed()` does not exist and should throw an error. (which you might only see when the console is open, explaining the issue) If you use `window.closed()`, try wrapping the code in a try/catch with an alert inside the catch clause to see the difference. I cannot reproduce the issue in IE11 when using `if (!windowobj.closed) {`. No matter if the console or open is not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the value of `window.closed` won't have any difference no matter the console is open or not. If you want to check if the window is closed, you should modify your code like this:

```
windowobj = window.open(
    url,
    "_blank",
    "resizable=yes,width=1024,height=630,top=0,left=0,status=1"
);

setInterval(function () {
    if (!windowobj.closed) {
        checkChild
       }
}, 500);
```

You could also refer to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp) and try [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_closed) in IE, the test result won't be changed no matter the console is open or close.